# I want to create a program that filter the number using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a `.txt` file that has a number in it. Let say that number is set to `var`.

How can I write a program that filter `var`? I.e. on text change execute

**Pseudo Code:**

```
if var == 9 digits
then 
    write only the last 8 digits of the number and overwrite the .txt file

if var ==> 9 digits 
then 
    write only the last 7 digits but add 0 in front and overwrite the .txt file

if var == 8 digits 
then 
    do nothing and overwrite the .txt file with same name
```

I'd like to write this using batch file in Windows.

Comment: What you are looking for is [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html). To check whether a number has more than, say 8 digits, use `if "%var:~,-8%"==""`. What do you mean by the very last comment?

Comment: There is a strlen function in https://www.dostips.com/DtCodeFunctions.php#_Toc128586394 you could use to base your if's on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to start moving into PowerShell.

```
$thefile = './thenumber.txt'
$var = Get-Content -Path $thefile
if ($var.Length -eq 9) {
    $($var.Substring($var.Length - 8)) | Out-File -FilePath $thefile -Encoding ascii
} elseif ($var.Length -gt 9) {
    $('0' + $var.Substring($var.Length - 7)) | Out-File -FilePath $thefile -Encoding ascii
} else {
    # seemingly useless
    $var | Out-File -FilePath $thefile -Encoding ascii
}
```

Place the code above into a file `last9.ps1`. It can be run from a cmd.exe prompt.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\last9.ps1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
setlocal 

call  :convert 12345678
call  :convert 123456789
call  :convert 1234567890

goto :eof

:convert
set var=%1
if "%var:~8,1%" == "" (
  echo less than 9 digits
  echo %1 -- %var%
  goto :eof
)
if "%var:~9,1%" == "" (
  echo exactly 9 digits
  echo %1 -- %var:~-8%
  goto :eof
)
echo more than 9 digits
echo %1 -- 0%var:~-7%
```

when needed, add two more `if`'s to check if `< 8` or `> 10`